# SQL more elegant combination of boolean checks possible?

Tags: sql

Call me pedantic but is there a more elegant way to combine all those checks?

```sql
SELECT * FROM [TABLE1] 
WHERE [path] = 'RECEIVE' 
AND [src_ip] NOT LIKE '10.48.20.10' 
AND [src_ip] NOT LIKE '0.%' 
AND [src_ip] NOT LIKE '127.%' 
ORDER BY [date],[time] DESC;
```

To something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM [TABLE1] 
WHERE [path] = 'RECEIVE' 
AND [src_ip] NOT LIKE IN ('10.48.20.10','0.%','127.%', .... ) 
ORDER BY [date],[time] DESC;
```

Comment: please note that I fixed my answer after you have accepted it (without the fix the address 10.48.20.100 would match the regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression. In MySQL that would be something like

```
select * from [TABLE1]
where [path] = 'RECEIVE'
and [src_ip] not regexp '^(10\\.48\\.20\\.10$|0\\.|127\\.)'
order by [date], [time] desc
```

In Oracle it might be something like

```
select * from [TABLE1]
where [path] = 'RECEIVE'
and not regexp_like([src_ip], '^(10\.48\.20\.10$|0\.|127\.)')
order by [date], [time] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Related, if you are using Oracle:

[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1675747400346669051](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1675747400346669051)

Comment: the regex in that article is wrong, there is a `.` missing in front of the `*` (which is redundant anyway)